# Como consolidar (agregar ou agrupar) os valores em uma base de dados?

Tags: r, data.frame, data.rable-r, plyr, dplyr

Suponha que eu tenha a seguinte base de dados

```r
vendas<-c(100,140,200,300,20,1000,200,3000)
vendedor<-c("A","B","A","B","C","C","D","A")
regiao<-c("Norte","Sul","Leste","Norte","Sul","Norte","Leste","Sul")
df<-data.frame(vendedor,regiao,vendas)
```

E queira analisar o total de vendas por vendedor e por vendedor/região.

Como faço para gerar essa nova base com os dados agregados para análise?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

O Hadley criou recentemente o `dplyr`, uma versao bem mais rapida e com sintaxe mais intuitiva que o `plyr`. (links [para o CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) e para [o anuncio no blog do RStudio](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/))

No `dplyr` ficaria assim

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df,vendedor)%>%summarise(Total=sum(vendas))
  vendedor Total
1        A  3300
2        B   440
3        C  1020
4        D   200
```

E agrupando por vendedor e regiao

```
group_by(df,vendedor, regiao)%>%summarise(Total=sum(vendas))
   vendedor regiao Total
1        A  Leste   200
2        A  Norte   100
3        A    Sul  3000
4        B  Norte   300
5        B    Sul   140
6        C  Norte  1000
7        C    Sul    20
8        D  Leste   200
```

Edição: a versão mais recente do `dplyr` usa o operador `%>%` do `magrittr`.

Answer (score 12):

Outra opção é utilizar o pacote [`data.table`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html):

```r
df <- data.table(df)
df[,sum(vendas), by=vendedor]
df[,sum(vendas), by=data.table(vendedor, regiao)]
```

Pacotes como o `plyr` e o `data.table` foram criados para facilitar e agilizar esse (e outros) tipos de análises, entao se o teu banco for grande ou tiver que fazer muitos agrupamentos, talvez valha a pena dar uma estudada neles!

Answer (score 11):

Você pode fazer isso com a função `aggregate`

```r
aggregate(vendas ~ vendedor,
          data=df,
          FUN=sum)

  vendedor vendas
1        A   3300
2        B    440
3        C   1020
4        D    200

aggregate(vendas ~ vendedor + regiao,
          data=df,
          FUN=sum)

  vendedor regiao vendas
1        A  Leste    200
2        D  Leste    200
3        A  Norte    100
4        B  Norte    300
5        C  Norte   1000
6        A    Sul   3000
7        B    Sul    140
8        C    Sul     20
```

Uma outra opção é usar o pacote `plyr`

```r
library(plyr)

ddply(df,
      c("vendedor"),
      summarise,
      total = sum(vendas))

  vendedor total
1        A  3300
2        B   440
3        C  1020
4        D   200

ddply(df,
      c("vendedor", "regiao"),
      summarise,
      total = sum(vendas))

  vendedor regiao total
1        A  Leste   200
2        A  Norte   100
3        A    Sul  3000
4        B  Norte   300
5        B    Sul   140
6        C  Norte  1000
7        C    Sul    20
8        D  Leste   200
```

Answer (score 6):

Você também pode utilizar `tapply`:

Por vendedor:

```
with(df, tapply(vendas, vendedor, sum))
 A    B    C    D 
3300  440 1020  200
```

Por vendedor e região:

```
with(df, tapply(vendas, list(vendedor, regiao), sum))
  Leste Norte  Sul
A   200   100 3000
B    NA   300  140
C    NA  1000   20
D   200    NA   NA
```

Answer (score 5):

Outra opção é usar sqldf

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT vendedor, sum(vendas) from df group by vendedor")
sqldf("SELECT vendedor, regiao, sum(vendas) from df group by vendedor, regiao")
```