# Como agrupar dados por um id em R

Tags: r, data.frame, script, dplyr

Tenho a seguinte base de dados:

```
id     x
1      2
1      3
2      3
3      3
3      3
3      3
```

Queria criar uma nova base de dados sem repetição do valor do campo `id`, para resolver isso posso fazer a média dos valores campo `x` que pertence o mesmo `id`.

A minha pergunta é: Como posso fazer isso em `R`?

Answer (score 4):

Há várias formas de fazer isso no R, o que você quer é agregar uma variável usando outra como grupo. Essa pergunta do SOpt fala exatamente sobre isso e vai te ajudar ( [Como consolidar (agregar ou agrupar) os valores em uma base de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7527/como-consolidar-agregar-ou-agrupar-os-valores-em-uma-base-de-dados?rq=1) ).

Mas dando uma resposta para o seu caso específico, diferente da resposta do molx.

Recriando os dados:

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
id     x
1      2
1      3
2      3
3      3
3      3
3      3", header = TRUE)
```

Usando o `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dados <- data.table(dados)
dados[ , list(x = mean(x)), by = id]
 id   x
1:  1 2.5
2:  2 3.0
3:  3 3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer em `base` com a função `aggregate`:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), x=c(2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3))
aggregate(x~id, df, FUN=mean)
#  id   x
#1  1 2.5
#2  2 3.0
#3  3 3.0
```

Com `dplyr` (um pacote muito útil pra manipulação de dataframes):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(x=mean(x))
#mesmo resultado
```

Comment: Opa, respondemos na mesma hora exatamente a mesma coisa! Vou alterar minha resposta.

Comment: Pois é, depois de 6 horas respondemos a mesma coisa com 30s de diferença, hahaha.