# Aplicar função em grupos de dados

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Preciso separar os dados em grupos e realizar os cálculos em dois ou tres grupos/dimensões.

Encontrei a função tapply, ela resolve o problema. Com ela eu consigo o que preciso utlizando a função média, soma, etc.

Porém agora, percebi que preciso homogeinizar os dados nos grupos selecionads, logo, no lugar da função de ser média, soma e etc, eu preciso criar uma função que homogeinize e, então, aplicar no tapply. Creio que a minha função de homogeinização está com problemas, mas não consigo indentificar o que.

Tentei com o dplyr, data.table, agreggate seguindo a idéia do link ao lado, mas todas dão erro.
[Como consolidar (agregar ou agrupar) os valores em uma base de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7527/como-consolidar-agregar-ou-agrupar-os-valores-em-uma-base-de-dados)

Abaixo segue o codigo que tenho:

```
   bairro <- c("B_FLORESTA", "B_PINHEIRAO", "B_PINHEIRAO", "B_PINHEIRINHO",
                "B_LUTHER KING", "B_LUTHER KING", "B_VILA NOVA", "B_VILA NOVA",
                "B_NOVA PETROPOLIS", "B_VILA NOVA", "B_INTERIOR", "B_ALVORADA",
                "B_SADIA", "B_SADIA", "B_SADIA", "B_SADIA", "B_SADIA", "B_SADIA",
                "B_SADIA", "B_JUPTER", "B_JUPTER", "B_FLORESTA", "B_ITALIA",
                "B_ITALIA", "B_ITALIA", "B_ITALIA")

    tipo <-   c("CASA", "CASA", "COMERCIAIS", "CASA", "CASA", "COMERCIAIS",
                "APARTAMENTO", "APARTAMENTO", "APARTAMENTO", "APARTAMENTO",
                "SITIO", "APARTAMENTO", "CASA", "CASA", "CASA", "CASA",
                "TERRENO", "TERRENO", "CASA", "CASA", "CASA", "CASA",
                "CASA", "CASA", "CASA", "CASA")

    valor <-  c(1167, 2500, 1125, 2286, 400, 400, 1500, 1500, 300, 1500, 555,
                973, 2500, 2556, 2500, 2556, 600, 850, 2338, 1857, 1857, 2000,
                2000, 2063, 2000, 2063)

    data <-   c("2015_07", "2015_07", "2015_07", "2015_07", "2015_07", "2015_07",
                "2015_07", "2015_07", "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08",
                "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08",
                "2015_09", "2015_09", "2015_09", "2015_09", "2015_09", "2015_09",
                "2015_09", "2015_09")

    dados <- data.frame(bairro, tipo, valor, data)

    x <- tapply(dados$valor, list(dados$tipo, dados$data, dados$bairro), median)

## ok, esse é o resultado final 1.
```

Até aqui blz, mas agora, preciso homogeinizar, **é aqui onde está o meu problema!!** Segue abaixo uma  das funções para isso:

```
homo <- function (a){
        a <- a[order(a$valor),] # ordenar o pvalor
        n <- nrow(a)
        a
        for(i in 1:n){
          a$sobra[i] = round(((a$valor[i+1] / a$valor[i])*100)-100, dig = 2)
        }

        a <- subset (a, a$sobra < 50)   # ponto de corte < 50
        return (a)
      }
```

Ao aplicar a função "homo" no tapply, dá erro.

```
tapply(dados$valor, list(dados$tipo, dados$data, dados$bairro), homo)
```

Algém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda de @Pierre Lafortune, segue a resposta:

```
  library(dplyr)    
  dados %>% group_by(tipo, data, bairro) %>%
            arrange(pvalor) %>%
            mutate(sobra = round(((lead(pvalor) / pvalor)*100)-100, dig = 2)) %>%
            filter(sobra < 50) %>%
            summarise(pvalor = mean(pvalor))
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que está sendo passado um vetor para a função `homo()` (`dados$valor`) e dentro dela tu está tratando ela como um data.frame/lista (tentando chamar `a$valor`, entre outros.)

Abaixo uma função `homo()` que funciona, mas não sei se é o resultado que tu queria (não consegui entender o que tu considera por homogeinizar):

```
homo <- function (a){
        a <- order(a) # ordenar o pvalor
        n <- length(a)
        sobra <- rep(NA, n -1)
        for(i in 1:n){
          sobra[i] = round(((a[i+1] / a[i])*100)-100, dig = 2)
        }

        a <- subset(a, sobra < 50)   # ponto de corte < 50
        return(a)
      }
```

Alem do erro de considerar como lista, também corrigi um erro que aconteceria no `for(i in 1:n)`, onde tu tentaria chamar uma posição inexistente (`n+1`).

Comment: Rcoster, obrigado por responder a minha questão.

Poderia explicar melhor o que vc disse: "O problema é que está sendo passado um vetor para a função homo() (dados$valor) e dentro dela tu está tratando ela como um data.frame/lista (tentando chamar a$valor, entre outros.)"

A sua função dá resultado diferente da minha.

Apliquei sua função no comando tapply e deu errado, esse é o problema. Quando aplica-se a função no commando tapply, dá erro.

Como a função deve ser escrita para que em conjunto com o tapply funcione??

Comment: O primeiro parâmetro do `tapply()` é repassado para a função `homo()`. O problema é que tu está especificando um vetor (`dados$valor`, ao invés de `dados`), e a função está esperando um data.frame (a primeira linha da tua função tenta ordenar as linhas de `a`, além de chamar a coluna valor através do `a$valor`). E acabei de testar aqui, a minha função funciona dentro do tapply dado no enunciado - mas, como disse, o resultado provavelmente não é o que tu esperava, uma vez que não foi dito o que a função `homo()` devia fazer - o que eu fiz foi arrumar para ela não dar erro.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, o que posso fazer para resolver isso?

Comment: Fazer as correções que eu apontei, além de testar em um exemplo mais simples (talvez só com uma variável categórica) - assim fica mais fácil entender o [não-]funcionamento da função, além de conferir o valor resultante.

Comment: Obrigado cara, consegui fazer dar certo com a função dplyr!