# Como agrupar dados no R?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma função no R que possibilite fazer uma espécie de "agrupamento" dos dados. Por exemplo, uma forma de fazer com que essa planilha me retornasse algo como:

```
Codigo   Grupo  Qtde  Total 
  3219  Vacina     3    293
```

Desde já agradeço!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dados de teste:

```
dados <- data.frame(Codigo = c(3219, 3219, 3219, 3865, 3865, 3865),
                    Grupo = c('Vacina','Vacina','Vacina','Estética','Clínico','Clínico'),
                    Qtde = c(1, 1, 1, 19, 1, 1),
                    Total = c(58.00, 160.00, 75.00, 760.00, 170.00, 0.01))
```

Comment: Beatriz, boa noite! Você pode utilizar o group_by do dplyr: `dados %>% group_by(Codigo, Grupo)%>%
  summarise(Qtde = sum(Qtde, na.rm = T), Total = sum(Total, na.rm = T))`

Comment: Perfeita a resposta do @lmonferrari. Só não entendi pq a pergunta foi sinalizada como fora de escopo. Provavelmente é uma pergunta duplicada...

Comment: @LuizZ Por exemplo, [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7527/como-consolidar-agregar-ou-agrupar-os-valores-em-uma-base-de-dados).

Comment: Sim, foi o que eu imaginei, @Rui. Trata-se de uma dúvida comum. Por isso achei que deveria estar sinalizada como duplicata, e não como fora de escopo. Para não dar a sinalização equivocada para os novos usuários. Mas não sei, é só minha opinião