# Como consolidar strings em vetores, identificados por um id em comum? [R]

Tags: r, dplyr

De forma bem resumida, o que preciso fazer é o mesmo que [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7527/como-consolidar-agregar-ou-agrupar-os-valores-em-uma-base-de-dados), mas no meu caso os valores que quero consolidar são strings, não inteiros. Tentei dar uma mexida na função que resolveu o caso do OP do post citado, mas sem sucesso.

De forma mais prática, tenho um dataframe desse tipo:

```
ID <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
Palavras <- c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9")
df <- data.frame(ID, Palavras)

> df
  ID Palavras
1  A       P1
2  A       P2
3  A       P3
4  B       P4
5  B       P5
6  B       P6
7  C       P7
8  C       P8
9  C       P9
```

E preciso que deixá-lo dessa maneira:

```
  ID Palavras
1  A       P1, P2, P3
2  B       P4, P5, P6
3  C       P7, P8, P9
```

Tentei as funções group_by e summarise do dplyr, e também as consolidações do pacote data.table, mas não consegui chegar db que quero. Meu objetivo é rodar uma análise de sentimentos com esses dados. Qual seria uma forma de consolidar os dados dessa forma?

Answer (score 6):

Qualquer das seguintes maneiras faz o que a pergunta pede.

### R base

```
aggregate(Palavras ~ ID, df, paste, collapse = ", ")
#  ID   Palavras
#1  A P1, P2, P3
#2  B P4, P5, P6
#3  C P7, P8, P9
```

### Pacote `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Palavras = paste(Palavras, collapse = ", "))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  ID    Palavras  
#  <chr> <chr>     
#1 A     P1, P2, P3
#2 B     P4, P5, P6
#3 C     P7, P8, P9
```